# Disable Radiant Quests in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm a completist. I like to finish EVERYTHING. Skyrim creates a problem for me, it never ends.

Is there a way to disable radiant quests, perhaps in the console?

Is there a downside to disabling radiant quests? Do certain "real" quests require completion of a radiant quest?

Comment: Many real quests use radiant or 'miscellaneous' quests as breadcrumbs and/or prerequisites. For example, a number of Thieves Guild quests only unlock after a certain number of the random Radiant jobs have been done.

Comment: On a more serious note, I think you'd be better served by picking up a copy of the official strategy guide or otherwise assembling a list of 'real' quests, than by trying to hack around this aspect of gameplay.

Comment: In some cases, the Radiant quests are painfully obvious (I'm looking at you, Dark Brotherhood) and easy to avoid.

Comment: As a recovering TES completionist, let me tell you: You are doing it wrong. TES games used to become almost a job for me to slog through each misc. task for random dudes... but no more. I have so much more enjoyment by simply allowing myself to do whatever I feel like and ignore things that seem more dull, menial, or simply unsuited for my character. Try playing the game more organically and let Skyrim come to you. You really will enjoy it more.

Comment: Also, to help facilitate your itch to experience the whole game, try playing multiple characters in a more organic fashion, instead of a single deity-like character through everything. Play a heavily armored, melee-centric barbarian to completion (ignoring the college and thieves guild, but doing Companion quests), then do a full mage build, or a stealthy assassin. That way you can carve off chunks of the content into logical pieces that fit thematically, without it becoming a chore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no current way to do this.  As well, many of the actual quests use aspects from the Radiant quest system.  For instance, the quest *Laid to Rest* determines the race of the boss based on the Radiant system.  This can also determine race and gender of many other NPCs.

There are two places where radiant quests will end up in your journal.  They will either end up in the Miscellaneous tab, or in one of the Faction specific quest sections of your journal.  Therefore, you know that you are done with the game's completion as soon as you have finished the capstone quest for each faction, and have no other quests outside the Miscellaneous section.

Comment: do all radiant quests go in misc? for example missions from the night mother are Radiant but get put in normal part of the log. i think they are called "The Dark Brotherhood Forever"

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, and fixed.  Radiant Quests will go to either the Miscellaneous section, or the appropriate Faction section.

Answer (score 3):

Plain and simple, I don't believe it's possible. So, no.

Also, as some of the comments pointed out, even if you *could*, there would be strong drawbacks and consequences for doing so.

Answer (score -3):

You are both wrong, it is possible to remove radiant quests from journal.

You use the console, it isn't difficult.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how? Just saying they're wrong and not backing it up with how to do so isn't real helpful.

Comment: @john You can use the "edit" link to expand your answer if you choose to do so.